# Is it possible to use Soap API using Almofire in Swift 2.2

Tags: soap, swift2, alamofire

I am using  both Rest & Soap API in my iOS application .For Rest API I can easily use Alamofire for both POST  & GET method .But in Case of SOAP ,I am not able to handle the XML response .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse SOAP API using Alamofire and SWXMLHash Libraries easy to use for parsing : -

#### Swift 2.2

```
//MARK:- Parsing API here
 func parseMyApi(is_URL: String, completion: (result: String) -> Void) {

   Alamofire.request(.GET, is_URL)
            .responseJSON { response in
                    let xmls = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)
                    func enumerate(indexer: XMLIndexer, level: Int) {
                        for child in indexer.children {
                            let name:String? = child.element!.name
                            print("\(level) \(name)")
                            // Take Link from XML data here 
                            if name! == "link" {
                                let text = child.element!.text
                                if text?.isEmpty == false{
                                   print(text)
                                  // Finish here Process
                                  completion(result: text!)
                                }
                            }
                            enumerate(child, level: level + 1)
                        }
                    }
                enumerate(xmls, level: 0)
            }
       }
}
```

And you can see [this example](https://github.com/ANSCoder/Weather-App-Demo) also for Soap parsing.